# Reading xlsx file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm following [this tutorial](http://matthom.com/archive/2010/04/14/read-microsoft-office-2007-files-with-php) to read the `xlsx` file format.  I'm reading xlsx file. Working fine. But it display all the file content in one line. How to add space between them? Thanks
Here is my code.

```
    $file_upload = 'book.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
// the string variable that will hold the file content
$file_content = " ";
// the uploaded file
//$file_upload = $file -> upload["tmp_name"];
if ($zip -> open($file_upload) === true) {
  // loop through all slide#.xml files
  if ( ($index = $zip -> locateName("xl/sharedStrings.xml")) !== false ) {
                    $data = $zip -> getFromIndex($index);

                    $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

                    $file_content = strip_tags($xml -> saveXML());
              }
echo $file_content;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. Just add this line.
`$xml->formatOutput = true;` Full code here.

```
        $file_upload = 'book.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
// the string variable that will hold the file content
$file_content = " ";
// the uploaded file
//$file_upload = $file -> upload["tmp_name"];
if ($zip -> open($file_upload) === true) {
  // loop through all slide#.xml files
  if ( ($index = $zip -> locateName("xl/sharedStrings.xml")) !== false ) {
                    $data = $zip -> getFromIndex($index);
                    $xml->formatOutput = true;
                    $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

                    $file_content = strip_tags($xml -> saveXML());
              }
echo $file_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Tested on PHP 5.5.3

```
$file_upload = 'book.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// the string variable that will hold the file content
$file_content = " ";
// the uploaded file
//$file_upload = $file -> upload["tmp_name"];
if ($zip->open($file_upload) === true) {
    // loop through all slide#.xml files
    $index = $zip->locateName("xl/sharedStrings.xml");
    if ($index !== false) {
        $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
        $dom->loadXML(
            $data,
            LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING
        );
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $file_content = strip_tags($dom->saveXML());
    }
}
echo $file_content;
```